# Unable to install docker due to umet dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Tags: 16.04, package-management, docker

Even before installing docker on Ubuntu 16.04 machine, while going through some pre requisite steps, I am encountering this error that I cannot figure out:

```
root@11.22.33.44:~# apt-get install \
     apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.2.32).
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20170717~16.04.2).
curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libperl-dev : Depends: libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4 is to be installed
 libperl5.22 : Breaks: libperl5.22:i386 (!= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 is to be installed
 libperl5.22:i386 : Depends: perl-modules-5.22:i386 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6)
                    Breaks: libperl5.22 (!= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4 is to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4 is to be installed
        Depends: libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4 is to be installed
        Recommends: rename but it is not going to be installed
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.9) but 0.96.20.8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@11.22.33.44:~#
```

Output for a suggested command:

```
:~# apt policy libperl-dev libperl5.22 perl-modules-5.22 software-properties-common python3-software-properties
libperl-dev:
  Installed: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6
  Candidate: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6
  Version table:
 *** 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.22.1-9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libperl5.22:
  Installed: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4
  Candidate: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6
  Version table:
     5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.22.1-9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
perl-modules-5.22:
  Installed: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4
  Candidate: 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6
  Version table:
     5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
 *** 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5aka9.0.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.22.1-9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
software-properties-common:
  Installed: 0.96.20.8
  Candidate: 0.96.20.9
  Version table:
     0.96.20.9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 0.96.20.8 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.96.20 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
python3-software-properties:
  Installed: 0.96.20.8
  Candidate: 0.96.20.9
  Version table:
     0.96.20.9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 0.96.20.8 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.96.20 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt policy libperl-dev libperl5.22 perl-modules-5.22 software-properties-common python3-software-properties`?

Comment: @ByteCommander, I added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some incompatible versions of the mentioned packages from any third party repo or manually downloaded archives.

This repository (if it was one) is no longer configured, so we don't need to disable it any more.

However, we need to revert/upgrade those incompatible packages back to supported versions provided by the official Ubuntu repositories to resolve the conflicts. This can normally be done by explicitly  specifying the version you want for each package in `apt`'s arguments:

```bsh
sudo apt install libperl5.22=5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 perl-modules-5.22=5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 software-properties-common=0.96.20.9 python3-software-properties=0.96.20.9
```